# Parallelization and H.264 (or probably any compression codec)? Why's it so hard?

Tags: video, compression, h.264, video-encoding, parallel-processing

My limited (and probably wrong?) understanding of video compression is that intra-frames are completely independent.  In other words, all the picture data for a intra frame (key frame) is stored in its entirety for that frame.  It's the following inter frames (P and B frames in H.264, I think) that depend on the data in other frames to be "drawn."

If these intra frames are completely independent, why isn't encoding an embarrassingly parallel problem?  If you had N processors and X I-frames, you could just give X/N chunks of the source to each processor to encode independently, then patch them all together at the end, right?  But it seems that this isn't the case--or at least, I haven't seen any encoders that have the kind of parallelization that being able to do this would give.  What am I not understanding?

Comment: I always thought hardware acceleration of H.264 was made on the GPU, and that somehow implied parallelization...

Comment: I'm voting to close because this isn't a programming question. But since you asked, the embarassingly parallel part is all of the pixels within a single frame. A single 1920x1080 video frame has 8000 16x16 blocks of pixels that can all be processed simultaneously.

Comment: @Gabe: In H.264 the macroblocks can't in general be processed in parallel as the encoding process for each depends on the results of macroblock encoded close by in the same frame. Typically the block image will be predicted based on the block to the left of it and those in the row above it. Then only the difference gets coded. (This is different to older codecs like MPEG-2 where the blocks were more independent and could be parallelized in this way).

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to consider is where you want to put your intra frames. For the best compression you need to choose this wisely, preferring scene changes to the middle of a static sequence for example. To find the best places you need to analyse the raw video, which can either be done in an extra pass (expensive) or it can be decided on the fly as you encode.

So to parcel up the stream into chunks you either need to make an extra pass to analyse it or just arbitrarily divide it up and lose some compression efficiency.

Then you have to think about how you've got this raw video to encode. Either it's streaming into your compression program from somewhere or the whole thing is available on disk.

If it's streaming then you're out of luck as you don't have random access to different parts of the stream. Yes, you could buffer it but a quick calculation shows that this would either need a LOT of memory or you'd have to buffer to disk, which leads on to the next point:

If you have the whole raw file stored locally then you could parcel out portions to different processes or threads. Except that your problem would now be disk access! Consider that the data rate for raw 1080p, 24fps video is about 4 GB per minute. With a single process encoding it the disk will be heavily occupied providing the raw data. It could even be the slowest part of the process (though probably not unless your hard-drive is very fragmented!)

Now think about getting 4 processes to access the same file, all trying to grab the raw data at extremely high rates. This hard-drive just won't be able to keep the encoders fed with data - the weak link won't be slow processors but slow data access.

So unless you've got some really professional kit to store your uncompressed video, parcelling up different sections for parallel encoding just isn't practical yet.

Comment: 4GB/minute (~70MB/s) is not an issue for 10k+ HDDs, and won't break a sweat on fast SSDs like Crucial RealSSD; SSDs are particularly effective here as the access can be totally random.

Comment: @iconiK: The real speed you get depends on how fragmented the data is, and under good conditions a single process should be fine, it's multiple processes competing that proves difficult. Good point about SSDs, but they are still premium hardware. The one you mention is about £500 for the top model (256GB), and for that you could store only about an hour of raw HD video.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Parallelization makes it work faster.

In fact, the x264 encoder provides parallel encoding ability.

http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html